# Change the value MTframe.CanGoForward of the MyToolkit

Tags: xaml, uwp, mytoolkit

I am using MyToolkit MtFrame class for paging in my UWP app. I need to change the value CanGoForward but is an only-read value.

Comment: Yes, you can't change it as it's `readonly`

Comment: But at the beginning it is false but when calling a function it is set to true.

Comment: With GoBackAsync() the value change

Comment: It's not you, the developer, who decide whether the backward navigation can happen or not.